# How to Customize a .NET Build?

Tags: javascript, .net, msbuild, build

I want to customize a .NET build process so that I can run an executable ([a Javascript minimization program](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)) across all my Javascript files before deployment.  I've searched on the web, and I am not seeing a good way to do something like this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the [Yahoo one and MSBuild](http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/05/how-to-create-a-yui-compressor-msbuild-task/). Just change it to work with jsmin instead. I'm sure if you Google MSBuild and jsmin you will find an exact match...

Update- [this looks like a C# port of JSMin](http://www.raboof.com/Projects/Jazmin/) complete with an MSBuild task.

Answer (score 1):

Use the post-build event. Project properties -> build -> post-build